# openURL and YouTube

Tags: iphone, youtube, openurl

Is there any way to open the YouTube app from my app, with a defined search query?
If not, is there a way to just *open* YouTube, without playing any video?
All I'm finding is ways to play videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to open the YouTube *app* without a video.

Answer (score 0):

If you just navigate to `http://www.youtube.com`, that will obviously "just *open* YouTube, without playing any video" -- so I imagine you're after something fancier, but I can't guess what.  `http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=foobar` will open with a search query for `foobar` -- again, **what** exactly are you after, besides such elementary mashup issues?

Comment: No guessing here. I just really want to open YouTube without playing any video. Already tried both of these URL. None of them does what you describe.

Comment: @Sam V, I'm nonplussed -- what are you claiming is happening if you navigate to the bare homepage, http://www.youtube.com, for example?

Comment: However http://youtube.com/v/IDENTIFIER does open in the YouTube app. Looks like it's the only way to open the YouTube app. Can you second this?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you specifically didn't want *safari* involved! I believe you've hit on the way to do that now (but I don't know how to extend it for searches).

Comment: I did say the YouTube *app*. And no, I still don't have a clue on how to just open the app without playing any video.